# How to switch keyboard layout in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, keyboard-layout

I have WSL installed on Windows 10. I chose the default setup for WSL that provides Ubuntu, with support for GUI apps such as Google Chrome.
My locale and keyboard is set to US English.
Now I want to add an alternate keyboard layout (Hebrew) in Ubuntu, and have a way to switch on-the-fly between the two keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the keyboard layout inside WSL is possible using the
[setxkbmap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap)
command, but you may get into conflicts with the Windows keyboard layout.

It's much safer to install your keyboard layouts in Windows and to
switch them in Windows.

References :

- [Manage the input and display language settings in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-the-input-and-display-language-settings-in-windows-12a10cb4-8626-9b77-0ccb-5013e0c7c7a2)
- [Windows keyboard layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/windows-keyboard-layouts)

Comment: So it's easier than I even dreamed. I didn't realize that my Windows method for switching keyboard layouts would switch the layout also in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

To add an alternative keyboard layout (Hebrew) and switch between the two keyboard layouts in Ubuntu within WSL on Windows 10, you can follow the steps below:

1. open a terminal in ubunto inside WSL
2. To check the available keyboard layouts, you can run the following command: localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts
   2.1. This will list the available keyboard layouts
3. To set the Hebrew keyboard layout, use the following command (replace "he" with the Hebrew keyboard layout code if necessary): sudo localectl set-x11-keymap he
4. You can now switch between keyboard layouts using the "Alt+Shift" key combination. This will allow you to quickly switch between the Hebrew keyboard layout.
   NOTE: remember that you can replace "he" with the correct Hebrew keyboard layout code if it is different. make sure the Hebrew keyboard layout is installed on Ubuntu within WSL for this to work. I look forward to your feedback to see if I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora Workstation, you can use this shortcut:

> Shift + Super + Spacebar